# How to achieve replacement using regular expression?

Tags: perl

```
$test="111222333345555";
```

How to replace the digit of same repeated digits to 't'?

That is, how to get `"11t22t333t4555t"` using a regular expression?

Comment: I cannot find a way to have `"333t3"` and `"555t"`

Comment: @Faibbus Oh,I fixed.Sorry..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace when there are 2 or more same consecutive digits:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my $test = "11222333345555";
$test =~  s/((\d)\2*)\2/$1t/g;
say $test;
```

**Output:**

```
1t22t333t4555t
```

**Explanation:**

```
(       : start group 1
  (     : start group 2
    \d  : a digit
  )     : end group 2
  \2*   : backreference on group 2 (ie: same digit) 0 or more times
)       : end group 1
\2      : backreference on group 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"(\d)(\1+?)\1(?!\1)" [1]` with `"\1\2t" [2]`.

In `[1]`, you'll match a digit (`\d`) followed by itself any number of times (`\1+?`), followed by itself (`\1`) and followed by anything else (`(?!\1)`).

And you'll replace it by said digit, followed by all of its occurences but the last one, followed by `"t"`